# Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $H \cap K = \{e\}$. Then $H \cup K$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$ such that $H \cap K = \{e\}$. Then
>   $H \cup K$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I know that $H \cup K$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $H \subseteq K$ or $K \subseteq H$ but I'm not sure how that helps here.

Is the above statement true or false?

Comment: This is completely unrelated, but it helps to relate this in the linear algebra sense.

Comment: @Nameless Why unrelated? Vector spaces are abelian groups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false. Let $ |H|=3, |K|=2$ then $|H\cup K|=3+2-1=4$ if it is a subgroup, it contains $H$, which means it has to have an element of order $3$, but Lagrange says this is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

It is false. Take $G = \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} \times \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$, $H = \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}\times \{0\}$ and $K = \{0\} \times \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $G=(\Bbb{Z}_{10},+)$. Let $H=\{0,5\}$ and $K=\{0,2,4,6,8\}$. Then $H\cap K = \{0\}$. $H\cup K$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: How about $G=(\Bbb{Z}_{6},+)$. Let $H=\{0,3\}$ and $K=\{0,2,4\}$? Then also $H\cap K = \{0\}$ but $H\cup K$ is *not* a subgroup of $G$ since $H\cup K = \{0,2,3,4\}$ is not closed under addition.